# shifting PHP files to .TXT output

Tags: webserver

Is it theoretically possible to transform PHP files to raw plaintext?

I can add the .txt after the server-side programming language extension, but if it is rendered in the wrong content-type, is it theoretically possible for an attacker to obtain the php source-code in plain text by doing things with the url?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. PHP files are just plaintext. You can change the name and extention to whatever you want.

Comment: @Anders i mean is it for an attacker possible to do this (not for the owner)

Comment: @tebegi7454: Do you mean if an attacker can access the source code of the script instead of the result of the executed script by doing some tricks with the URL? With a properly configured server not, but with a broken server configuration or bugs in the web application this might work. But details depend on the configuration, i.e. in which way it is broken. There is no generic attack for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ok that's I was looking for, can you turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is it theoretically possible for an attacker to obtain the php source-code in plain text by doing things with the url?

There is no inherent feature within a web server or a URL which makes it possible to get the source code of a PHP file from remote.

But, this does not mean that it is impossible in all cases. For example a bad server configuration might unwillingly expose the source code. Or a bug in the web application might allow read access to files on the server, including the PHP files. Or due a bug in some file upload feature an attacker might be able to upload its own PHP script which allows this kind of access. And sometimes none of this is even needed since the source code is available from some badly secured software repository.

Comment: Good summary. This was missing some common related mistakes, so I added them as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's why it's hard to get the source code of a php program from a properly configured web server.

php web apps are hosted in web server software like [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) and [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/).  Those servers' configuration files are rigged so they don't deliver files with names ending in `.php`, but rather pass them to the program that runs the php script interpreter. In nginx that configuration looks something like this (thanks to Digital Ocean for a great [runbook for this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04).) It says, in the nginx configuration language, *any file ending in `.php`, send it to php, and don't deliver it as a file.*

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

The same goes for apache servers, with a different configuration language. Other server software can also serve php apps in the same way.

So, a cybercreep would need to change that configuration file and restart the server in order to download the php source code.  In 2020, that's very hard to do on a server with a best-practices security configuration.

Comment: *"... a cybercreep would need to change that configuration file ..."* - this is assuming that the only way the source code could be accessed is due to changes in the configuration. But, another part of the configuration could accidentally offer direct access to the source code. Or bugs in the web application could allow reading of arbitrary files on the server, including the PHP files. Thus it might be less hard than your answer shows if the attacker only knows where exactly to look.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't probably save your `config.php` files under name `config.php.txt`, and if the server is properly configured to process `.php` files instead of sending their contents, there wouldn't be any problem. However, I've seen **some pitfalls worth to mention and avoid**:

- Automatic **backup files** created by text editors. Typically these are only saved during the file edit, which may be an adequate window for an attack in itself, but if the text editor is interrupted, it may not be able to remove its backups. Therefore, there might be a `config.php.bak`, `config.phpbak`, `config.php-bak`, `config.php~` or similar left hanging on the server, and that can be abused to access the source code.

  - This has a bad practice cousin of keeping old versions with `config.php.bak` `config.php.old`, `config.php.20200405` etc. If that's even necessary, the naming pattern should always be `config.what-ever-versioning.php`, ending with the extension `.php`.
- **Legacy file extensions**. While `.phtml` & `.php3` were standard extensions before PHP4, they aren't anymore, and most servers aren't configured to interpret those extensions as PHP. Yet, they have been around on legacy applications, and if they are only `include()`d in or `require()`d by other scripts with `.php` extensions, they might not break the application, but accessed using the direct path they do expose the source code.
- Another *name based virtual host* having the same document root (or its parent), but without PHP processing. This is why you should check the configuration for the default virtual host before just adding new ones.